# App Crashes When Changing the Streams Playing on the Chromecast

Tags: android, google-cast

I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.VideoCastManager$29.onPostExecute(VideoCastManager.java:2274)
        at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.VideoCastManager$29.onPostExecute(VideoCastManager.java:2271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It happens when I'm replacing the media stream currently playing on the Cast device. The media stream changes and plays, but the app crashes.

Here are the logs:

```
10-02 13:22:32.717      531-917/? W/ActivityManager? Unable to start service Intent { pkg=com.burakradio cmp=com.burakradio/com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.reconnection.ReconnectionService } U=0: not found
10-02 13:22:32.717  24997-24997/com.burakradio I/NowPlayingFragment? remoteMediapPlayerMetadataUpdated ++++++++++++++
10-02 13:22:32.717  24997-24997/com.burakradio I/NowPlayingFragment? com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaMetadata@283a09f3
10-02 13:22:32.717    531-25730/? W/ActivityManager? Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.action.notificationvisibility pkg=com.burakradio cmp=com.burakradio/com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService (has extras) } U=0: not found
10-02 13:22:32.747      531-992/? I/MediaFocusControl? Remote Control   unregisterMediaButtonIntent() for PendingIntent{226daff8: PendingIntentRecord{21cfad10 com.burakradio broadcastIntent}}
10-02 13:22:32.757     531-1286/? W/ActivityManager? Unable to start service Intent { pkg=com.burakradio cmp=com.burakradio/com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.reconnection.ReconnectionService } U=0: not found
10-02 13:22:32.757      531-903/? W/ActivityManager? Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.burakradio/com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService } U=0: not found
10-02 13:22:32.897  24997-25127/com.burakradio D/dalvikvm? GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3530K, 30% free 26660K/37608K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
10-02 13:22:33.177  24997-24997/com.burakradio D/AndroidRuntime? Shutting down VM
```

I am looking forward for any help/suggestions...

Comment: If you have any issues with the CastCompanionLibrary, please use the GitHub's project to file a ticket there. When you do, please make sure you are running th every latest build (from the head) and provide more information, for example an expanded log, and how you are 'replacing" streams, etc.

Comment: The app crashes when sending the mCastManager.loadMedia(mMediaInfo, true, 0); command if I don't stop the playback with mCastManager.stop(). If I use stop() however, loadmedia does not work again...

Comment: Please do not continue with this thread here and instead open a ticket on GitHub and put your information there. Later on you can come back here and put the final outcome for others to follow.